# Compilation stops on 'loading the extended glyph list from ConTeXt'

Tags: miktex

I have updated yesterday the MikTex-Portable to the lastest version (Version: 4938, Date: 7/9/2013, Packages: 608).

The following MWE on windows 7

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

causes the compilation stops here:

```
[....]
(C:/Util/Port/MikTeX/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(C:/Util/Port/MikTeX/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(C:/Util/Port/MikTeX/tex/latex/euenc/eu2enc.def)
(C:/Util/Port/MikTeX/tex/latex/euenc/eu2lmr.fd)
luaotfload | db : Font names database not found, generating new one.
luaotfload | db : This can take several minutes; please be patient.
luaotfload | db : Failed to save names database
luaotfload | db : Database creation unsuccessful.
luaotfload | load : loading the extended glyph list from ConTeXt
lua>
```

By the way: It seems that a "Font name database" should be generated. It took some time (about 45 sec). I have not had this before.

Where (path) does MikTeX want to save this database?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See this discussion http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.luatex.user/4442.

Comment: @Ulrike, it seems that the newest version of luaotfload causes the error. After restore a 2 days old backup and updating all packages execept the luaotfload-package everything works fine.

Comment: This seems to be working for me in an up-to-date MiKTeX. Do you still see the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved with an update of the underlying LuaTeX engine, cf. this mail list thread http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.luatex.user/4442.